# update JSON using the Unix timestamp with jQuery.

Tags: jquery, json, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have the following JSON object to maintain the mobile content hosted by 3rd party:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contentInfo = {};

    contentInfo.mobileContent = {
        "global" : 
        {
            "headerBanner": 
            {
                "img" : "http://www.myDomain.com/assets/someImage.png",
                "url" : "http://www.myDomain.com/newPage.html"
            }
        },

        "home": 
        {
            "bodyBanner": 
            {
                "img" : "http://www.myDomain.com/assets/imageDefault.png",
                "url" : "http://www.myDomain.com/newPage2.html"
            }

        }
    };
</script>
```

I need to update the default bodyBanner content to the following:

```
"bodyBanner": 
{
"img" : "http://www.myDomain.com/assets/importantMessage.png",
                "command" : "displayOverlay",
                "parameters" : { "path":"http://www.myDomain.com/popup.html" }
}
```

at 6pm GMT on 03/06 2014 and should be changed back to default bodyBanner at 10am GMT on 03/07 2014.

Can someone help me with this update using the Unix timestamp with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of this?

```
var start = new Date(2014, 3, 6, 6);
var end = new Date(2014, 3, 7, 10);
if (Date.now() > start && Date.now() < end) {
contentInfo.mobileContent['home']['bodyBanner'] = {
                "img" : "http://www.myDomain.com/assets/importantMessage.png",
                "command" : "displayOverlay",
                "parameters" : { "path":"http://www.myDomain.com/popup.html" }
                }
}
```

Please read more about the Date object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to ensure the timezones are what you intended, etc.